# open file in different directory to read lines - ruby

Tags: ruby, file, directory

I've been using ARGV to open files but i feel like its clunky i want to have them in a different folder.

i want to open input.txt within my talk_parser.rb, I don't want to hardcode the file name either.

My directory (pwd is bin)

```
├── bin
│ └── talk_parser.rb
└── data
  └── input.txt
```

tried

```
x = Dir.glob('../data/*.txt').to_s
file = File.open(File.expand_path(x))
```

but i get this error

```
talk_parser.rb:34:in `initialize': 
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/huvi/Desktop/test/bin/["../data/input.txt"] (Errno::ENOENT)
from talk_parser.rb:34:in `open'
from talk_parser.rb:34:in `<main>'
```

not sure what to do

Comment: `Dir#glob` returns an `Array`. In this case your `Array` will be every "*.txt" file in "/home/huvi/Desktop/test/data/" so for starters you should probably be looping through these files. If you only want the first one then change your first line `to_s` to `first`. Right now you are calling `to_s` on an `Array` thus your output `'["../data/input.txt"]'`

Comment: Can you use `..` in `Dir::glob`?  Or should it be `x = Dir.glob('**/data/*.txt').first` (assuming one file in `data` dir)?

Comment: @orde good point. technically you can use `..` in `Dir::glob` although it has very strange results that I am having difficulty understanding

Comment: @engineersmnky:  Yeah.  Strange results indeed.  Oh well...vacation beckons ;)

Comment: Can you explain the difference, I've been trying to use RSpec to test and when i have 
    `Dir.glob('../data/*.txt').first`
it works when i do ruby run.rb but not in RSpec. Then in RSpec it works when i have 
`Dir.glob('**/data/*.txt').first` but doesn't work when i run the program from the bin folder? @engineersmnky @orde

Comment: for some reason `Dir.glob('../**/data/*.txt').first` works in both

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dir.glob returns an `Array`.
You can get the first element and open it:

```
  path = Dir.glob('../data/*.txt').first
  file = File.open(path)
```